# How to tell when a script object is deleted?

Tags: maxscript

I have a controller object that I attach other helper nodes to as weak references. The script listens to the transform events of those other nodes and then does stuff..

The problem is that when I delete the controller object, I have no way of stopping the WHEN listeners.

1. "on delete" clause fires whenever the gc wants basically, often times only after I close max.
2. the nodePreDelete event fires at the right time but runs in global scope and I have no clue how to find the script instance that I actually need
3. "when this deleted" doesn't do anything, worth a shot I guess

Meanwhile I can't have transform scripts running on broken objects in the background forever, it seems like such a simple concept, is there even a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

---EDIT----
Can you outline more precisely what you're doing, because after re-reading this, I'm pretty unclear as to how you're handling your notifications; I assumed that you were using a script controller, but it seems you're using the when construct... can you post a snippet of the bit causing issues.

---EDIT----

There are a few ways to handle it in maxscript. None of which is clean...

One way that might at least save you from error spamming, is to wrap your script code in a try/catch. Your catch should "zero" the scripted controller, maybe even print to the a warning to listener.

As a quick FYI, the referenceTarget/referenceMaker interfaces seem to be specifically meant to handle this kind of thing. MAxscript sadly doesn't implement this, AFAIK.

http://help.autodesk.com/view/3DSMAX/2017/ENU/?guid=__files_GUID_1395FB57_C374_4DDF_B3E1_56492DBC27A4_htm

Comment: Pretty much everything in max is a referenceTarget and thus a referenceMaker. This is the scenetree in max. Notifications are more for UI updates.

Answer (score -1):

You should never be listing objects by name in script controllers if that is what you are doing. You should be creating parameters and adding nodes directly.

You can then use isValidNode nodeParam and check if it valid before trying to do anything with it.